# What does a while after a print mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop, statement-modifiers

I am new to Perl, but I know a little bit of C though. I came across this snippet in one of our classroom notes:

```
$STUFF = "C:/scripts/stuff.txt";

open STUFF or die "Cannot open $STUFF for read: $!";

print "Line $. is: $_" while (<STUFF>);
```

Why is the `while` after the `print` statement? What does it do?

Comment: **`WARNING`** Do not use this code, it's poorly written.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, I hadn't even noticed what it was doing with the filehandle.  That's evil.

Comment: Why is it bad? Plz explain. I do not wish to name the author; BTW the book that is referred is not a standard reference book, its just somebody's notes.

Comment: It relies on an extremely crufty special-case behavior that made a *tiny* bit of sense to have in Perl 4, but is an increasingly bad idea in Perl5 -- various current Perl best practices (running under `use strict`, using lexical variables) are incompatible with it, and it's just kind of nasty to begin with.  `open STUFF, 'c:/scripts/stuff.txt'` is not just far better form, but simpler and easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the same as

```
while (<STUFF>) {
    print "Line $. is : $_";
}
```

It's written the way it is because it's simpler and more compact.  This is, in general, Perl's <sub>(in)</sub>famous "statement modifier" form for conditionals and loops.

Comment: I'd disagree that it is "simpler" (if it were, this question would not exist!)

Comment: It is simpler.  What it isn't is intuitively obvious to every person for every background.  When you're judging whether two things are simpler or more complex relative to each other, I really think you have to work with the assumption that the viewer knows what both mean, rather than saying "oh, this is more complex because I know C and not Perl".

Comment: It's more compact, not necessarily simpler. I find it about as simple, but I've known Perl for a while now.

Comment: What I really mean is that it's simpler in an Occam's Razor sort of sense: it requires fewer entities.  Enclosure-form conditionals and loops in Perl require a BLOCK, and therefore its enclosure characters (and its indentation, if one has any class at all); statement-modifier form does not.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers have explained the statement modifier form of the `while` loop. However, there's a lot of other magic going on here. In particular, the script relies on three of Perl's special variables. Two of these (`$_` and `$!`) are very common; the other (`$.`) is reasonably common. But they're all worth knowing.

When you run `while <$fh>` on an opened filehandle, Perl automagically runs through the file, line by line, until it hits `EOF`. Within each loop, the current line is set to `$_` without you doing anything. So these two are the same:

```
while (<$fh>) { # something }
while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) { # something }
```

See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), the section on I/O operators. (Some people find this *too* magical, so they use `while (my $line = <$fh>)` instead. This gives you `$line` for each line rather than `$_`, which is a clearer variable name, but it requires more typing. To each his or her own.)

`$!` holds the value of a system error (if one is set). See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), the section on `$OS_ERROR`, for more on how and when to use this.

`$.` holds a line number. See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), the section on `$NR`. This variable can be surprisingly tricky. It won't necessarily have the line number of the file you are currently reading. An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print "$ARGV: $.\n";
}
```

If you save this as `lines` and run it as `perl lines file1 file2 file3`, then Perl will count lines straight through file1, file2 and file3. You can see that Perl knows what file it's reading from (it's in $ARGV; the filenames will be correct), but it *doesn't* reset line numbering automatically for you at the end of each file. I mention this since I was bit by this behavior more than once until I finally got it through my (thick) skull. You can reset the numbering to track individual files this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print "$ARGV: $.\n";
}
continue {
    close ARGV if eof;
}
```

You should also check out the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas and take a look at the newer, three-argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). I just noticed that you are "[unknown (google)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136207/unknown-google)", which means you are likely never to return. I guess I got my typing practice for the day, at least.

Comment: Good lord! And i thought C was the most complicated language. Perl does a lot of hidden things too. As far as unknown(google) is concerned, i am a student right now; too many teachers here for me to expose myself :-), maybe later i will try to be myself. I have given you your +1 BTW :-)

Comment: I wasn't worried about the rep (though thanks). It just would have been a shame to type all that and _not_ get it read. Glad you saw it. 

I have minimal experience with C, so I can't compare. But my sense is that Perl's complications mostly make your life easier. Perl will very, very frequently automatically do what you want. It's a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

The following snippets are exactly equivalent, just different ways of writing the same thing:

```
print "Line $. is : $_" while (<STUFF>);

while (<STUFF>) {
    print "Line $. is : $_";
}
```

What this does is each iteration through the loop, Perl reads one line of text from the `STUFF` file and puts it in the special variable `$_` (this is what the angle brackets do). Then the body of the loop prints lines like:

```
Line 1 is : test
Line 2 is : file
```

The special variable `$.` is the line number of the last line read from a file, and `$_` is the contents of that line as set by the angle bracket operator.

Answer (score 4):

Placing the `while` after the print, makes the line read almost like normal English.

It also puts emphasis on the `print` instead of the `while`. And you don't need the curly brackets: `{ ... }`

It can also be used with `if` and `unless`, for example,

```
print "Debug: foobar=$foobar\n" if $DEBUG;

print "Load file...\n" unless $QUIET;
```

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your snippet as I would.

Below my suggested code is a rogues gallery of less than optimal methods you might see in the wild.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stuff_path = 'c:/scripts/stuff.txt';

open (my $stuff, '<', $stuff_path)
    or die "Cannot open'$stuff_path' for read : $!\n";

# My preferred method to loop over a file line by line:
# while loop with explicit variable
while( my $line = <$stuff> ) {
    print "Line $. is : $line\n";
}
```

Here are other methods you might see.  Each one could be substituted for the while loop in my example above.

```
# while statement modifier
# - OK, but less clear than explicit code above.
print "Line $. is : $_" while <$stuff>;

# while loop
# - OK, but if I am operating on $_ explicitly, I prefer to use an explicit variable.
while( <$stuff> ) {
   print "Line $. is : $_";
}

# for statement modifier 
# - inefficient
# - loads whole file into memory
print "Line $. is : $_" for <$stuff>;

# for loop - inefficient
# - loads whole file into memory;
for( <$stuff> ) {
    print "Line $. is : $_\n";
}

# for loop with explicit variable
# - inefficient
# - loads whole file into memory;
for my $line ( <$stuff> ) {
    print "Line $. is : $line\n";
}

# Exotica -

# map and print
# - inefficient
# - loads whole file into memory
# - stores complete output in memory
print map "Line $. is : $_\n", <$stuff>;

# Using readline rather than <>
# - Alright, but overly verbose
while( defined (my $line = readline($stuff) ) {
    print "Line $. is : $line\n";    
}

# Using IO::Handle methods on a lexical filehandle
# - Alright, but overly verbose
use IO::Handle;   
while( defined (my $line = $stuff->readline) ) {
    print "Line $. is : $line\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `while` statement can only follow your loop body if it's a one-liner. If your loop body runs over several lines, then your `while` has to precede it.

Comment: PERL borrows its syntax from several different languages, including English.

Allowing the conditional statement to follow a one-line block makes it read more like English.

You may also want to look at the `unless` and `until` keywords, which act like negated versions of `if` and `while`. This is something that C doesn't have as far as I know. Using it does sometimes improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as a:

```
while (<STUFF>) { print "Line $. is: $_"; }
```